# Flux Generator - How to handle when there are no data available?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, project-reactor, reactive-streams

**Question: How do we handle the [Flux Generator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.function.Consumer-) when there are no more data?**

I am using Project Reactor's Flux API to poll the data that are put in Redis (By external service). This needs to be indefinite poll until the service goes down/terminated/stopped.

I am using [Flux Generator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.function.Consumer-) to fetch the data from Redis. **There are cases where there will be no data available in Redis for some time** and hence Generator will not be able to call onNext. But I want to resume when there will be data available in Redis.

How do I handle this situation? I see below options:

1) call `onError` with custom exception stating that there are no data available at the time

2) call `complete` to signal - In this case, i am periodically creating Flux instance and the same will be completed when there will not be any data.

Answer (score 0):

`Flux.generate` is for a data-generating function that is guaranteed to always produce. Use either `Flux.create`[1] (if the Redis listener can be notified from multiple threads) or `Flux.push`[2] (if the Redis listener is guaranteed to be notified from a single thread).

[1] https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-

[2] https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#push-java.util.function.Consumer-